# Error reports of Force Closure - works on my phone

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I've had reports on my 'Ned Soundboard Free' App that there have been some force closures. It's only been installed by 4 users and three of them have HTC desire S phones the same as mine. I am unable to get the app to force close on my phone no matter how many buttons i try.

Here is the error code

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.stewart.nedfree.NedSoundboardFreeActivity$13.onClick(NedSoundboardFreeActivity.java:197)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's not even something i can look up in Eclipse (logcat) as its not something i can replicate.

Any hints on how to read from this?

Thanks a lot 
Paul

I'm keen to learn as i go without the help of others, so even if its a hint and not the solution i can work from there.

Comment: Could you show some code? Including line 197 of NedSoundboardFreeActivity?

Comment: what does the onClick do? Your error says NullPointerException which mean that whatever object is in your onclick, it is null at some point that causes the error.

Comment: I'll need to send it later from home as its on my laptop, however, on testing, the admob banner refreshes, and seems to take over the functionality of the app. I have set it to not refresh so i'll see if this still produces the errors. Maybe someone is clicking the buttons too many times as this also crashes the app. Goodness i have work to do lol

Answer (score 0):

Rather embarrassing.

I'm proud that i looked into it further, however, its a good idea to call MediaPlayer.release(); to your media player.

On further reading i noticed that on the button click the media player will stay in memory and create a new instace of the player on every click. I had 25 buttons and in theory that was opening a new thread in memory. No wonder it was force closing on button clicks. Release takes the media player out of memory again, from what i gathered. 18 users of the app now with no reported errors.

We live and learn :)